# RegEx for failing subdomains

Tags: regex, iis, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Basically, I would like to check a valid URL that does not have subdomain on it. I can't seem to figure out the correct regex for it.

Example of URLs that SHOULD match:

- example.com
- www.example.com
- example.co.uk
- example.com/page
- example.com?key=value

Example of URLs that SHOULD NOT match:

- test.example.com
- sub.test.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we would start with an expression which is bounded on the right with `.com` or `.co.uk` and others, if desired, then we would swipe to left to collect all non-dot chars, add an optional `www` and `https`, then we would add a start char `^` which would fail all subdomains:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.com|\.co\.uk)(.+|)$
```

---

Other TLDs can be added to this capturing group:

```
(\.com|\.co\.uk|\.net|\.org|\.business|\.edu|\.careers|\.coffee|\.college)
```

And the expression can be modified to:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.com|\.co\.uk|\.net|\.org|\.business|\.edu|\.careers|\.coffee|\.college)(.+|)$
```

---

#### Flexibility

I can't think of something to make the TLDs too flexible, since this is a validation expression. For instance, if we would simplify it to:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.[a-z]+)(\.uk?)?[a-z?=\/]+$
```

it might work for the URLs listed in the question, but it would also pass:

```
example.example
```

which is invalid. We can only use this expression:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.[a-z]+)(\.uk?)?[a-z?=\/]+$
```

if we would know that what we pass, it is already a URL.

#### [NOT FUNCTIONAL DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/WUiowP/1/)

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.com|\.co\.uk)(.+|)$/gm;
const str = `example.com
www.example.com
example.co.uk
example.com/page
example.com?key=value

test.example.com
sub.test.example.com`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Nqbmb4/1/).

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Nqbmb4/1/)

Comment: How would you catch different TLDs other than .com? I tried `^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([^.]+)(\.[^.]+)(.+|)$` but that just matched everything.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to make it more flexible so that I don't have reconfigure each time we introduce a new TLD though I don't see that happening quite often.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

tweaked a bit to handle your /PATH example better

```
^(?<OptionalEmail>.*@)?(?<OptionalProtocol>http[s]?:\/\/)?(?:(?<ThirdLevelSubDomain>[\w-]{2,63})\.){0,127}?(?<DomainWithTLD>(?<Domain>[\w-]{2,63})\.(?<TopLevelDomain>[\w-]{2,63}?)(?:\.(?<CountryCode>[a-z]{2}))?)(?:[\/](?<Path>\w+))*(?<QString>(?<QueryStringSeparatorOrExtraJunk>[?&,])(?<QueryStringParams>\w+=\w+))*$
```